# mysqli-соединение, проблемы с кириллицей

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Из базы данных выдаются ?????? вместо кириллицы. В чем причина? В PHPmyAdmin таблицы и строки под кодировкой utf-8. При простой настройке БД всё нормально (через mysql) с установкой кодировки через set_charset(utf-8):

```
<?php mysql_select_db('nature', mysql_connect('localhost','root','')); mysql_set_charset("utf8");?>
```

А вот через эту настройку (код ниже) при запросах в БД выдаются вопросы. Помогите! Мне нужен именно данный вариант:

config.php

```
<?php
//site specific configuration declartion
define( 'BASE_PATH', 'http://localhost/php-quiz/');
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '');
define( 'DB_NAME', 'nature');

function __autoload($class)
{
    $parts = explode('_', $class);
    $path = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$parts);
    require_once $path . '.php';
}
```

DBclass.php

```
<?php
class Cl_DBclass
{
    /**
     * @var $con will hold database connection
     */
    public $con;

    /**
     * This will create Database connection
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
            mysqli_character_set_name('utf8');

        mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
        $this->con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");


        if( mysqli_connect_error()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
   mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
   $this->con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

"Когда я сначала надеваю трусы, а потом брюки, то всё нормально. А если сначала брюки, а потом трусы, то почему-то все смеются." *Наверное*, задавать кодировку соединения надо после того, как соединение установлено?

**Но это не единственная проблема.**

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Здесь мы видим, что вывод ошибок в коде задавлен в ноль. Иначе РНР уже давно бы объяснил тебе, в чем проблема. Читаем, как *правильно* обращаться к функциям mysqli: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php

И больше никогда не отключаем вывод ошибок в РНР.

Comment: Если после ставлю - всё равно не работает. ?????? выдает.

Comment: Какие еще проблемы?